# Update SQL statement in php with javascript on a submit button

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a php page (a formular) that I can change the values.
When I click on submit, I want to update my table with the new values.

Could you help me do it? 
I post my code, which does not the work because I am certainly missing something.

```
    <?php 
    //echo '<input id="input_itf" type="text" value="'.$vara.'"><br>';
    $requete = mysql_query("update `names` set `vara`=$vara, `varb`=$varb, `varc`=$varc, `vard`=$vard, `vare`=$vare, `varf`=$varf, 
    `varg`=$varg, `varh`=$varh, `vari`=$vari, `varj`=$varj, `vark`=$vark, `varl`=$varl, `varm`=$varm, `varn`=$varn
    `varo`=$varo, `varp`=$varp, `varq`=$varq, `varr`=$varr, `vars`=$vars, `vart`=$vart, `varu`=$varu, `varv`=$varv WHERE `id`=$id");
    $sql = stripslashes($requete);
    $req=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        while($d=mysql_fetch_array($req))
                { 
                    $nb_trouve++;                   
                    $id=$d['id'];
    $nb_trouve=0;


    mysql_close();
?>
```

Many thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Do you get any error?

Comment: Missing '}' in your while statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your while block is missing a closing bracket `}`.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `mysql_query` twice and a closing bracket was `}` missing too..

Try this...

```
<?php 

//echo '<input id="input_itf" type="text" value="'.$vara.'"><br>';
$requete = "update `names` set `vara`='$vara', `varb`='$varb',`varc`='$varc', `vard`='$vard', `vare`='$vare', `varf`='$varf',`varg`='$varg', `varh`='$varh', `vari`='$vari', `varj`='$varj', `vark`='$vark', `varl`='$varl', `varm`='$varm', `varn`='$varn'`varo`='$varo', `varp`='$varp', `varq`='$varq', `varr`='$varr', `vars`='$vars', `vart`='$vart', `varu`='$varu', `varv`='$varv' WHERE `id`='$id'";
$req=mysql_query($requete) or die(mysql_error());
while($d=mysql_fetch_array($req)){
    $nb_trouve++;
    $id=$d['id'];
    $nb_trouve=0;
}


mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Hello all, many thanks for your replies. I did try what you told me, but my query is not working, it should update my table but it doesn't do it. I also noticed that the update is not happening WHEN I click on my Submit button at the end of my formular (I want to only update the table when I validate on Submit).

Comment: @tom Try adding slashes to `$var`. `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv` and remove `stripslashes`

Comment: @ Malik : what do you mean add slashes, like that: `vara`=/$vara/

Comment: @ Malik I don't understand where to put the slashes, I put them in the query like /$vara/ but it is not working either